# Conditional "pragma omp"

Tags: c, macros, openmp, pragma

I am trying different kinds of parallelization using OpenMP. As a result I have several lines of `#pragma omp parallel for` in my code which I (un-)comment alternating. Is there a way to make these lines conditional with something like the following, not working code?

```
   define OMPflag 1 
   #if OMPFlag pragma omp parallel for
   for ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An OpenMP parallel construct can have an `if` clause specified.  In Fortran I'd write something like this:

```
!$omp parallel if(n>25) ...
```

I sometimes use this when a problem might be too small to bother parallelising.  I guess you could use the same approach to check a debug flag at run time.  I'll leave it up to you to figure out the C++ syntax but it's probably exactly the same.

Comment: I found the details here: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#Combined -> OpenMP Directives

Comment: Hm, the question is about C, neither C++ nor fortran.

Answer (score 7):

C99 has the `_Pragma` keyword that allows you to place what otherwise would be `#pragma` inside macros. Something like

```
#define OMP_PARA_INTERNAL _Pragma("omp parallel for")
#if [your favorite condition]
#define OMP_FOR OMP_PARA_INTERNAL for
#else
#define OMP_FOR for
#endif
```

and then in your code

```
OMP_FOR (unsigned i; i < n; ++i) {
  ...
}
```