# Using an openmp pragma inside #define

Tags: c, macros, openmp, c-preprocessor, pragma

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C/C++ pragma in define macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030099/c-c-pragma-in-define-macro)
>   [Conditional “pragma omp”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085595/conditional-pragma-omp)

How can I use an OpenMP pragmas inside a macro definition? E.g.

```
#define A() { \
 ...a lot of code... \
 #pragma omp for     \
 for(..)             \
  ..do_for..         \
 ...another a lot of code \
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was answered here [Conditional "pragma omp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085595/conditional-pragma-omp/4087196#4087196)

> C99 has the `_Pragma` keyword that allows you to place what otherwise would be `#pragma` inside macros. Something like

```
  #define OMP_PARA_INTERNAL _Pragma("omp parallel for")
```

So,

```
#define OMP_PARA_FOR _Pragma("omp for")
#define A() { \
 ...a lot of code... \
 OMP_PARA_FOR     \
 for(..)             \
  ..do_for..         \
 ...another a lot of code \
 }
```

several `_Pragma`s can be combined as unary operator, e.g.:

```
_Pragma("first pragma") _Pragma("Second pragma")
```

Answer (score 2):

On Visual Studio you can use the [`__pragma`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx) keyword instead of `#pragma`. Unfortunately, this is non-standard so you'll have to figure out whether your compiler supports something similar, if you're using another compiler.

Comment: I'm using a GCC compiler, is here something like `__pragma` keyword?

Answer (score 1):

You can't because `#` inside a macro has another meaning (to add quotes (`#somevar`) or concat variables (`onevar ## anothervar`)).
If you've got more complex code you'd like to include in-place instead of a function call, use a local function and add the `inline` keyword so it's inlined just as a macro would be inlined. You just have to ensure you pass variables used inside as parameters (as pointers or references). As an alternative you could use `#include` to include a code file containing your macro code only.